# how to set route with token as query string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using devise and trying to use token code with devise registration page, I know I have some issue with the routes to set the link. The link looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up.asdfsdfasdffffffffffffffasdfasdf
```

a dot in between the query string and it doesn't work.

my routes.rb is this

```
    devise_for :users ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } do
        #get "/register", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
          get 'users/sign_up/:invitation_token' => "registrations#new", :as =>        :reg_with_code
      end
```

please help me to set a proper link with the slash in between .

here is may rake routes

```
    invitations GET    /invitations(.:format)                     invitations#index
                     POST   /invitations(.:format)                          invitations#create
      new_invitation GET    /invitations/new(.:format)                 invitations#new
     edit_invitation GET    /invitations/:id/edit(.:format)            invitations#edit
          invitation GET    /invitations/:id(.:format)                 invitations#show
                     PUT    /invitations/:id(.:format)                   invitations#update
                     DELETE /invitations/:id(.:format)               
    invitations#destroy
           reg_with_code GET    /users/sign_up/:invitation_token(.:format)    registrations#new
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                  devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                    registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                           registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                   registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                      registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                           registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                           registrations#destroy
users GET    /users(.:format)                           users#index
                     POST   /users(.:format)                           users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                       users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                  users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                       users#show
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                       users#update
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                       users#destroy
                root        /                                          home#index
```

Comment: how your view looks like?

Comment: Can you show what your `rake routes` output is?

Comment: view is an email template

Comment: Are you sending the users the registration link via email, it might be possible that they are getting the link in their email which has a period instead of a slash? If so, then can you show the part where you are rendering the url in the template.

Comment: This is the link  <%= link_to "Sign Up",new_user_registration_url(@token) %>

Answer (score 0):

In the email template, change the token link to

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up", reg_with_code_path(@token) %>
```

since you have put a `:as => :reg_with_code` in you `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Gives this now Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"new", :invitation_token=>nil}

Comment: still same error Gives this now Routing Error No route matches {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"new", :invitation_token=>nil}

Comment: Make sure that you your `@token` is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

`reg_with_code_path(invitation_token: @token)`